# Trying to show only a certain amount of numbers

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

To make the sale to my customer I need to import numbers from a report into an Excel document. For example the number coming in will be `14.182392`. The only reason for my guy not to buy the product is because he only wants to view `14.182` on the Excel sheet. Okay so the other catch is, the number CANNOT be rounded in any shape or form.

So what I need is a way to just show so much of number, WITHOUT ROUNDING.

Is this possible? Any ideas of how I could get around this would be fantastic.

Comment: Yes, this can be done by formatting to 3dp, the overall value of the cell should not be affected.

Comment: Hi Dave,

If i were to use the number 14.182392, if i use the dp. button . When i get to 14.18239.... the next time i click -1dp. the 3 gets rounded to a 4. hence affecting my overall number . 14.1824..  I cannot have the number rounded in any shape or fashion unfortunately.

Comment: I dont mind where the data is on the excel file, i will present it in a form that the user will view however the data can be manipulated in any way out of view of the user to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(INT(A1)+VALUE(LEFT(MOD(A1,1),5)),"00.000")
```

---

Firstly =TRUNC is a better answer (much shorter). My version was connected with uncertainty in your requirement (it is odd!) and in the hope it might be easier to adjust if not exactly what you/your boss wanted.

[TRUNC](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/TRUNC-function-b77557ab-c592-430a-9621-aa93dc69e5fa) literally just truncates the decimals (no rounding!) to a length to suit (ie `3` if to show `nn.182` given `nn.182392` or say `nn.182999`).

---

LEFT may also be a better choice, but that depends upon knowing how large the integer part of your number is. `=LEFT(A1,6)` would display `14.189` given say `14.189999` in A1. However it would show `1.4189` given `1.4189999` in A1 (ie four decimal places).

---

The formula above combines text manipulation with number manipulation.:

[INT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/int.php) takes just the integer value (here `14`.)

[MOD](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/VALUE-function-fd94fddd-e3ef-483b-8575-c7a3d01ff831) takes just the modulus – the residual that is not an integer after division, in this case by `1`. So just the `.182392` part. LEFT is then applied here in a similar way to as used above, but without needing to concern oneself with the length of the integer part of the source value (ie `14` or `1` etc does not matter).

[VALUE](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/VALUE-function-fd94fddd-e3ef-483b-8575-c7a3d01ff831) then converts the result back into numeric format (string manipulation functions such as [LEFT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) always return text format) so our abbreviated decimal string can then be added to our integer.

Finally, the [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58) part is for formatting but is hard or impossible to justify! About the only use is that it displays the result left-justified in the cell – perhaps a little warning that the number displayed is not the “true” value (eg it won’t [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUM-function-a1fe8ecc-2c5a-4d5a-8db0-80b9f7fcbd6b)) because, as a result of a formula, it won’t be marked with a little green warning triangle.

Comment: That worked brilliantly, can you just explain the logic slightly as i need to convince my boss / buyer that it is not rounding. (this is very vital). Thankyou for your answer!

Comment: thanks for this it's brilliant, it gives me more flexibility , the numbers coming in could be 1mm , 100mm, 1000mm or 0.812321mm. The way you have done this suits perfectly and I can adjust accordingly. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The displayed values can use the [TRUNC function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRUNC-function-b77557ab-c592-430a-9621-aa93dc69e5fa) like this,

```
=TRUNC(A1, 3)
```

But you must use A1 in any calculations to retain the precision of the raw value.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know:

```
=LEFT(A1; x)
```

where x = the amount of **characters** You want. Mind that the dot counts as a character as well.

Comment: I think that there are other functions/formulas that can provide some more universality than that. *114.182392, 14.182392* and *4.182392* would all require different *length* parameters for the [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Left-Function-D5897BF6-91F5-4BF8-853A-B63D7DE09681).

Comment: well VBA is also one of the tags, so he can write a simple script to determine where the dot is with the MID function.

For the word: Alphabet 
=MID("Alphabet", 5, 4)
Result: "abet"

But I think I have answered strictly the question.

Comment: This is just simple, and easy to explain to bosses/buyres :-)

Comment: Well pnuts, probably your answer is the best, I just gave an alternate possible solution to his problem. Harvey993 and other viewers will decide the one they need and can take best use of.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, great alternative , thankyou.